# using rapidapi api to make json file

Tags: python, api, sqlite, rapidapi

so i couldnt find any guide that fit for rapidapi,
im making an movie libary app
and i want to connect into their https://rapidapi.com/amrelrafie/api/movies-tvshows-data-imdb/endpoints
api with python and turn it into my own (preferably sqlite) then use it as a database for my app sqllite/json file
im really a beginner at this so sorry for my lack of knowledge i couldnt find a good guide for this anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Although, it has nothing to do with RapidAPI because the response format for that particular API is JSON.

However, you can convert JSON into an SQL database by following a few simple steps.

- Start the Perl File
- Connect to SQLite
- Open the JSON file
- Create a new table with necessary columns
- Loop through the JSON file
- Unpack JSON data, and insert it into our Table

Here is a good and detailed guide on how to do the same: https://codeburst.io/convert-raw-json-data-into-an-sql-database-using-sqlite-and-perl-489c921b8868